# Connecting to SQL Server in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, sql-server, apple-push-notifications

I have been researching this all day, its more of a question to see if anybody can help.

I have already set up the push notifications on my iPhone app which i had a nightmare with but I've managed to do so.

I'm only a internship and have been developing apps for 4 months, its not my strongest subject as I haven't learned anything like this at uni.

My boss has asked me to add a view to the application so that you can view the most recent push notification that the app has received.

I know this is possible but I'm not sure how it's done, I have spoken to the developer who dealt with all of the server side of things (he doesn't have any knowledge of app development).

He said I would need a page that will read directly from the SQL Server database which he has written the code for that stores all of the pushed notifications.

I have mentioned that it wouldn't be a good idea as it can be prone to hacking etc. He disagrees.

Can any one help with what I need to do? Or does any one know of any tutorials I can follow to help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. One route to take is to make a copy of that Database and put it on the phone as an SQLite Database and have a PHP script that gets the newest additions and adds them to the SQLite database.
2. A second route you could take, is you could ask him to put it JSON format and you would have a dictionary on the phone that held all of the JSON, and then parse the JSON using apples built in parser, `NSJSONSerialization` or any of the other JSON parsers out there. Using the parsed JSON, you could then do as you please with the list of notifications
3. Another method will be for that guy to write a PHP script for you to access all the notifications and you run that in a for loop and populate a table, or whatever, on the phone of the latest push notifications that way. This while take a few seconds longer than needed, depending on how many entries there are.

***Ordered according to my preference of options***

Since you fairly new to mobile app development I would recommend option 2 for you. It will be a bit more work than choosing option 3, learning curve wise, but it will run faster and be better for you to learn how to parse JSON, as a lot of API's that you come across use that format.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me, i'm a little over whelmed. I will need to speak to the guy doing the other stuff and plenty of research. Thanks again :)

Comment: @Sophia_xoox No problem. This video tutorial is quite good and highlights how you would parse json: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9MEnvlqP-wU